# Iterator return only 1 value (XML import)

Tags: java, xml, iterator

I use an iterator to collect my datas from an XML documents, but that doesn't return all the datas required.

```
//PROMOTION
    listImport = racine.getChildren("promo");
    i = listImport.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Element courant = (Element)i.next();
        name = courant.getChildText("name");
        photo = courant.getChildText("photo");
        percentage = Double.valueOf(courant.getChildText("percentage"));
        authCustomer = Boolean.valueOf(courant.getChildText("authCustomerOnly"));
        //creation promotion
        promotions.add(new Promotion(name, percentage, authCustomer));
        int index = promotions.size()-1;
        //ajout authCustomer
        promotions.get(index).setAuthCustomer(authCustomer);
        //ajout recettes
        List<Element> listRecettes = courant.getChildren("recipes");
        Iterator<Element> i2 = listRecettes.iterator();
        while(i2.hasNext()){
            Element sousCourant = (Element)i2.next();
            if(sousCourant.getChildText("recipe") != null) promotions.get(index).addRecipe(sousCourant.getChildText("recipe")); //TODO Recettes perdues après import (1 seule reste)
            else System.err.println("recipe == null, "+"Iterator value : "+i2.toString());
            System.out.println(sousCourant.getChildText("recipe"));
        }
        //ajout %age
        promotions.get(index).setPercentage(percentage);
    }
```

I think the problem came from here :

```
//ajout recettes
        List<Element> listRecettes = courant.getChildren("recipes");
        Iterator<Element> i2 = listRecettes.iterator();
        while(i2.hasNext()){
            Element sousCourant = (Element)i2.next();
            if(sousCourant.getChildText("recipe") != null) promotions.get(index).addRecipe(sousCourant.getChildText("recipe")); //TODO Recettes perdues après import (1 seule reste)
            else System.err.println("recipe == null, "+"Iterator value : "+i2.toString());
            System.out.println(sousCourant.getChildText("recipe"));
        }
```

Original XML File : [XML 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnCip.png)

An XML made after import : [XML 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcAbQ.png)

Comment: Without a complete [mcve] and example input files, it’s difficult to help you.  However, I suspect `int index = sauces.size()-1;` is supposed to be `int index = promotions.size()-1;`.  You could avoid this problem entirely by simply putting the new `Promotion` instance into its own variable before adding it;  this would remove the need for the `index` variable.  Also, you would be doing yourself a favor by learning about [enhanced for loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html);  they will make your code much esaier to read than using Iterators does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've change sauces to promotions but still not work. I'll try to make this code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to get all children tagged as `receipe`, and iterate over them

```
List<Element> listRecettes = courant.getChildren("recipes");
Iterator<Element> i2 = listRecettes.iterator();
while(i2.hasNext()){
  Element sousCourant = (Element)i2.next();

  // New code here
  List<Element> listrecipe = sousCourant.getChildren("recipe");
  Iterator<Element> i3 = listrecipe.iterator();
  while(i3.hasNext()){
    Element recipe = (Element)i3.next();
    promotions.get(index).addRecipe(recipe.getTextContent()); 

  }
}
```

Comment: @AlexiCourieux, kindly mark it as accepted as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)